# Message 'EXECUTE AS USER' failed for the requested user 'xxx' in the database 'yyy'. The step failed

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-job

Googled enough and found some solutions for this error which did't help me. All I am trying to do is:

1. Created a stored procedure:

   ```sql
   create procedure test
   as
   begin
       update dummytable set dummycolumn = 'abcd'
   end
   ```
2. Created a job - 'testjob' and run by the user who is the database owner.
3. Error I am seeing:

   > Message
   >   'EXECUTE AS USER' failed for the requested user 'xxx' in the database 'yyy'.  The step failed.
4. I tried: to reset the database owner, created a new user and scheduled the job, set the `TRUSTWORTHY` level of the database. Nothing helped.

Can someone help me fix this issue?

Comment: Can you do this: `update dummytable set dummycolumn = 'abcd'` with that user ?

Comment: Yes. When I run that query on a query window, it is working perfectly fine. I am also able to run couple of other jobs by the same user. Only this job is having issue.

Comment: How is that job set up? Executed as who?

Comment: Permission to execute an SProc is separate from permission to CRUD.  Make sure you have permissions and those permissions apply to your SProc.

Comment: @GSerg Job setup locally to be run within SQL. Set by the same user who is the owner of the database and also run by the same user.

Comment: @Duston Let me check the sproc permission

Comment: @Duston I granted all the execute permissions. Still no use

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20051234/11683?

Comment: @GSerg http://blog.strictly-software.com/2009/09/database-owner-sid-recorded-in-master.html - Found this link in the ticket you mentioned. Resetting the DB owner worked!! Yaayy!